# If I override window.onerror in javascript should I return true or false?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I want to log JavaScript errors so I'm overriding `window.onerror` like this:

```
window.onerror = function(message, file, lineNumber) {
    var browser_ = encodeURI(navigator.appVersion);
    var error_ = encodeURI("msg:"+ message + "\n\tfile:"+file+"\n\tln:"+lineNumber);
    var user_ = encodeURI("");

    ...

    return false;
}
```

I've seen some people return `true` and some return `false`. Which is right and why? One post mentioned something about have you have to return true or Firefox will handle the error it's own way. What??

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org) on [`window.onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onerror):

> When the function returns `true`, this prevents the firing of the default event handler.

<strike>See also chromium [Issue 92062](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=92062):</strike>

> In Chrome, returning `true` from window.onerror allows the error to propagate, and returning `false` suppresses it.
>
> This is the inverse of the behavior in Firefox and IE, where returning 'true' suppresses the error, but returning `false` propagates it.

**Note:** the issue mentioned above was fixed, behavior is now as mentioned on MDN for all browsers.

Comment: The Chrome behavior on it's face seem to be the way I would expect it to work... "error? false!"

Comment: @Tomasz You didn't answer which I should do! Also, what is an example of where you'd want to propagate the error? I guess that's a new question!

Comment: Opera 11.60 behaves like Chrome.

Comment: I just tried it out in FF and in Chrome they behave the opposite of each other. The effect of "prevents the firing of the default event handler" is that the dev tools will either report the error or not.

Comment: This seems not to be true anymore (?). Returning true in Chrome and Firefox stops the handler to propagate.